# PHP remove the word next to search string

Tags: php

i need to remove the next word of search string.. i have search array like array('aa','bb','é');

This is my paragraph    'Hello, this is a test paragraph aa 123 test bb 456'.

In this paragraph i need to remove 123 and 456.

```
$pattern        = "/\bé\b/i";
$check_string       = preg_match($pattern,'Hello, this is a test paragraph aa 123 test é 456');
```

How to get the next word?? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
<?php

//Initialization
$search = array('aa','bb','é');
$string = "Hello, this is a test paragraph aa 123 test bb 456";

//This will form (aa|bb|é), for the regex pattern
$search_string = "(".implode("|",$search).")";

//Replace "<any_search_word> <the_word_after_that>" with "<any_search_word>"
$string = preg_replace("/$search_string\s+(\S+)/","$1", $string);

var_dump($string);
```

You replace "SEARCH_WORD NEXT_WORD" with "SEARCH_WORD", thus eliminating "NEXT_WORD".

Comment: @Kathiravan: It does for me. What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: i dont know about preg_replace function preg_replace("/$search_string\s+(\w+)/","$1", $string); here $1 what will do.

Comment: It means that you replace the matching string with the first capture group (the first `(brackets)` occurrence, which means the search_word).

Comment: sorry.. Now its working fine. i replaced the wrong search array.. Thanks for your help..

Comment: Hi one doubt if i have the string like ref: REF-0025-1020CoRalisation d'interfaces, i want to remove this whole string REF-0025-1020CoRalisation what can i do to get the output.

Comment: @Kathiravan: You replace \w+ with \S+, which means "Any character that's not a space". (\w means Alphanumeric characters, and underscores).

Comment: wow!!! Thank you is there any reference to learn preg match, preg replace and all...

Comment: Sure! http://www.regular-expressions.info/ for Regex information, and the corrensponding manual page for `preg_replace()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use phps `preg_replace()` function for this:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

// the payload to process
$input = "Hello, this is a test paragraph aa 123 test bb 456 and so on.";

// initialization   
$patterns = array();
$tokens   = array('aa','bb','cc');

// setup matching patterns 
foreach ($tokens as $token)
  $patterns[] = sprintf('/%s\s([^\s]+)/i', $token);


// replacement stage
$output = preg_replace ( $patterns, '', $input );

// debug output
echo "input: ".$input."\n"; 
echo "output:".$output."\n";

?>
```